# Sorting nested objects with conditions using LINQ

Tags: c#, list, linq, sorting

I have the following definition:

```
public virtual DbSet<Groups> Groups { get; set; }
```

The ActionResult class contains the following statement:

```
var group = context.Groups.Single(s => s.Group_ID == details.Id);
```

The result structure of 'group' looks simplified as follows:

```
Group
{
    int Group_ID
    string Group_Name
    List Articles
}

Articles
{
   int Article_ID
   string Article_Name
   List Features
}

Features
{
   int ID
   string Feature_Name
   string Feature_Value
}
```

After some ToDo's the Code ends with the following return:

```
return View("GroupDetails", group.Articles);
```

**My question is: How can I sort with Linq all Articles by `Features.value` respecting the condition that for example `Features.ID == 2`.**

I have so far read similar questions here and also googled about it, but have not been able to find a solution so far. Unfortunately, the last OrderBy attempts e.g. `var result = group.Articles.OrderBy(a => a.Features.Where(f => f.Feature_ID == 2).Select(f => f.Feature_Value))` failed.

Comment: Do the orderby before the group.  The order will be maintained after the group is done.

Comment: What should happen if an article has several features with ID = 2? Or can you rule out that case?

Comment: @SomeBody: I can rule out that case. Its unique.

Comment: @jdweng: I'm probably on the fence, but when I do OrderBy(....).group.Articles, there is an error.

Comment: *"by `Features.value` respecting the condition that for example `Features.ID == 2`"* - read that part slowly, so you wanted `Article`s that have `Features.ID` is `2` and **then** order it by `Features_Value`? or do you want to order `Group` by those parameters? try workout a sample input and expected output, you might be able to [rubber ducking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) your way out.

Comment: @Bagus Tesa: Thanks for your tip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `FirstOrDefault` in your OrderBy clause:

```
var result = group.Articles.OrderBy(a => a.Features.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Feature_ID == 2)?.Feature_Value));
```

With `FirstOrDefault`, you only get one item back. If there is no item that matches your condition, the result of `FirstOrDefault` will be null, and with the null propagation operator you make sure that no null reference exception will be thrown.

If you use `Where` like in your approach, you will get an IEnumerable. But there is no way to sort after IEnumerables, hence you will propably observe no change of the order of your articles.

Comment: FirstOrDefault will not return all values.  You need to use SelectMany like in my answer.

Comment: @jdweng OP mentioned in a comment that the feature ids are unique.

Comment: @jdweng & SomeBody: It's something like this: I have 10 fruit groups. One of them is apples. Each apple in the group has a set of features like size, weight and color. So each apple in the group has the feature color, e.g. feature_ID: 1 with an indivdual value like for example feature_Value: Red

Comment: You can have a pear and banana that is yellow and my results will group all the yellow fruits.

Comment: @jdweng: Thank you for your solution. As I wrote in the question, the apples are already selected. So it's just a matter of sorting the apples by color. I have tried and tested SomeBody's approach and it works fine for me and is really smart. But I will save your approach for a possible later use.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use SelectMany :

```
           var results = group.Articles
                .SelectMany(x => x.Features.Select(y => new { Article_ID = x.Article_ID, Article_Name = x.Article_Name, Feature = y }))
                .Where(x => x.Feature.ID == 2)
                .GroupBy(x => x.Feature.Feature_Value)
                .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

The `OrderBy` method takes a lambda expression that defines the sorting criteria. Within the lambda expression, a represents each article in the group.Articles list. The `FirstOrDefault` method is used to find the feature with ID 2 within each article's list of features. If the feature is found, its Feature_Value is returned for comparison. If the feature is not found, `null` is returned.

```
var sortedArticles = group.Articles.OrderBy(a =>
{
    var feature = a.Features.FirstOrDefault(f => f.ID == 2); // Get the feature with ID 2
    return feature != null ? feature.Feature_Value : null; // Return the feature value or null if feature is not found
}).ToList();
```